# Fail to alert input text value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple `<input id="editfileFormTitleinput" type="text>`. I want to alert the text within the input text field but I fail. This is what I've tried:

```
$('#editfileFormTitleinput').on('input', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

I keep typing in the input text field things, but it only alerts `undefined`. How do I get the value of the input text field if not in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `attr` with `val`. `attr()` will return the value of the attribute but in `input` there is no `value` attribute defined. So it will alert `undefined`

```js
$('#editfileFormTitleinput').on('input', function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="editfileFormTitleinput" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#editfileFormTitleinput').on('input', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id = "editfileFormTitleinput" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it even more simpler like this

```
$('#editfileFormTitleinput').on('input', function() {
  alert(this.value)
});
```